# How to replace PropTypes with TypeScript Interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am using a reusable component in my React Project. That component passes some props for us to use as we like, and are required.

I am in a TypeScript file, and I am trying to convert the previous props, from PropTypes to a TS `interface`.

Below is the component along with the destructured Props and the interface:
The problem lies with the props: `callback, actualValue, label`.

```
interface RouteUserInfo {
  username: string;
  callBack: string;
  actualvalue: string;
  label: string;
}

export interface IState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  user: IUser | null;
  errorMessage: HttpResponseObj | null;
}

export class UserDetailsPage extends Component<RouteComponentProps<RouteUserInfo>, IState> {
  hasBeenMounted = false;

  state: IState = {
    errorMessage: null,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null
  };

render(): React.ReactNode {
    const { user, isLoading, errorMessage } = this.state;
    const { callBack, actualValue, label, match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid lenses-container-fluid">
        {this.renderNoResourceComponent()}
        <div
          className="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-center my-2"
          data-test="basic-render"
        >
          <div className="d-flex flex-row">
            <h2>{match.params.username}</h2>
            <span
              className="ml-3 my-2"
              onChange={callBack}
              value={actualValue}
              placeholder={label}
              data-tip
              data-event="mouseover"
              data-event-off="keydown mouseout"
              data-for="loggedIn"
            >
              {user.isActive ? <ActivityBadge isActive /> : <ActivityBadge />}
            </span>
          </div>
          {user && this.renderHeaderDropdown()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But I get the following error, when trying to use them like that on the `<span />` that says:

```
Type '{ children: Element; className: string; onChange: any; value: any; placeholder: any; data-tip: true; data-event: string; data-event-off: string; data-for: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'.ts(2322)
```

And on the actual props I get this:

**For the callback**

```
Property 'callBack' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<RouteUserInfo, StaticContext, any>>'.ts(2339)
const callBack: any
```

**For the actual value:**

```
Property 'actualValue' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<RouteUserInfo, StaticContext, any>>'.ts(2339)
const actualValue: any
```

**For the label:**

```
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<RouteUserInfo, StaticContext, any>>'.ts(2339)
const label: any
```

I obviously could use `:any` for all this properties but I would like to know their specific types, and the methodology on how to find them.

I also provide the reusable component itself:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTooltip, { Place } from 'react-tooltip';

import './styles.scss';

export interface Props {
  id: string;
  place?: Place;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
function Tooltip(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { children, id, place, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <ReactTooltip id={id} place={place} {...rest} className="tooltip">
      {children}
    </ReactTooltip>
  );
}
export default Tooltip;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you providing `value`, `onChange` and `placeholder` to a `span` ? If your span is some sort of controlled input then you should probably consider switching it for an actual `<input />` element, which will not complain about these props :)

Comment: No It is not. It is just a span with some css. That is how we use the component. We tie those attr in a span, and just call it. I actually solve this error a little differently. will post shortly..